# How to call restapi in .sh file

Tags: linux

I am trying to create a script to call restapi endpoint but I am getting "bad substitution" error.

Here is my script:

```
vi script.sh
echo "welcome to the script"
echo ${"http://web-integ000/sampleProject/getProductList"}
```

but when I execute the curl command at commandline it worked.I used the following command

```
$ curl -H "Accept:application/json" http://web-integ000/sampleProject/getProductList
```

and I got the following output:

```
[ {
  "productId" : "u1604028-5948abd0-0",
  "prodcutName":"H1ACX",
  "calendarDate" : "2017-06-20"
  }
 ]timeStamp:1497968810
```

How to get the response from the restapi using script?

Answer (score 11):

You can use a simple **curl** command to get the response from the server as follows:-

**rest.sh**

```
result=$(curl -X GET --header "Accept: */*" "http://localhost:9090/employees")
echo "Response from server"
echo $result
exit
```

Hope it works! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

$ evaluates a shell command or environment variable. A URL cannot be evaluated by the OS natively, so you should use the curl command for it, e.g.:

```
VAR1=${curl ....}
```

You can then use the variable, e.g. echo it.

Comment: I used this var1 = ${curl -H "Accept:application/json"  http://web-integ000/sampleProject/getProductList}

Comment: echo ${var1} then at coomand prompt I used ./script.sh I am getting var1:command not found. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: It is important not to place a space before or after the = sign.

Comment: I am grabbing timestamp value from the response and calculating numberofseconds from currenttime. I am getting expr: non-integer argument.how to expert long numbers in unix?

Comment: I did currentTime=$(date +$s) it is giving me currenttimeinseconds.